# Ambiguous Outer Join Error While Using OleDB to List all Stored Procedures and Queries

Tags: c#, ms-access, stored-procedures, ado.net, oledb

I have to document several MS Access 2007 databases, each with hundreds of macros queries, etc and I'd like to automate the process in C#. For every .mdb file, myfirst goal is to extract schema information (tables, forms, macros and query names and definitions).

I'm using the following code using OleDB to get a list of all available tables by the user:

```
 private static List<String> getTableNames(OleDbConnection db)
 {
        List<String> tableList = new List<String>();
        DataTable schemaTable;
        try
        {
            object[] objArrRestrict = new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" };
            schemaTable = db.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,objArrRestrict);
            foreach(DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows) tableList.Add((String)row["TABLE_NAME"]);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(`"Table Name Querying Failed. Returning Empty List"`);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return tableList;
    }
```

For the columns I'm using a similar method simply feeding off the previous one like so:

```
object[] objArrRestrict = new object[] { null, null, tableName, null };
schemaCols = db.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, objArrRestrict);
foreach (DataRow row in schemaCols.Rows) tableList.Add((String)row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
```

I'm not so sure how to get the macro information (name and definition), but after some research I decided to use the following to get the query information.

```
object[] objArrRestrict = new object[] { null, null, null, null };
schemaCols = db.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, objArrRestrict);
```

However when I run the last bit of code, I get the the very vaguely worded error message:

> > > `The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query in your SQL statement.`

After some more research I modified the getTableNames method to grab queries through the  "VIEWS" restriction, but that only got the stored SELECT queries in the data base and I also need the stored INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries.

Finally, I'm now using the following code to query the MsysObjects table directly.

```
String cmdString; 
OleDbCommand queries = new OleDbCommand(cmdString,db);
OleDbDataReader reader = queries.ExecuteReader();
```

Using the following two cmdStrings interchangeably:

> > SELECT MSysObjects.Name FROM MsysObjects WHERE (Left$([Name],1)<>"~") AND 
> >     (MSysObjects.Type)=5 ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name

or

> > SELECT Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE (Name Not Like ""MSys*"") AND (Type In (1,4,6))  ORDER BY Name

Again, both strings also induce the same "Ambiguous Outer Join" error.

I've read up a little bit on this type of error and I know the general recommendation is to break apart the original query into multiple queries but as I'm using library functions to get this schema data, I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing that. I've aready spent days researching this and I'm at my wit's end. If someone could help me out with this issue or point me toward some way to sidestep this roadblock I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is not a lot of help, but I tried a mock-up of your code and it worked for me.

Comment: @Remou It does help in a way, thanks. Most other people report that
'db.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, objArrRestrict);' should work as I'm using it. I rewrote the same code using VBA and I'm still getting an "Ambiguous Outer Join" error. I'm beginning to think that there is something wrong with the database itself. Also, I'm wondering if there is some way for me to fix this issue using the fact that I can get all the stored views (SELECT queries) to somehow filter them out before I call GetOleDbSchemaTable() on OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures.

Comment: Also, to be clear, OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures is the only filter that is giving me issues in OleDB right now. The others are working just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried working through the usually corrupt database routine: compact & repair, decompile etc ( http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm ) ? I would be wary of using the system tables outside of Access, there are permissions problems that are hard to work around.

Comment: I had those permissions issues very early on, but I've long since fixed them. Right now I'm just trying to deal with this mysterious "Ambiguous Outer Join" error that always breaks at the GetSchemaTable line. I could probably do all of it by hand but there are so many tables and queries, you can imagine how desperate I'm trying to avoid doing all of that column tracking manually.

Comment: Just ran compact and repair without a hitch. I'm still getting this error, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you group it like this?

```
SELECT 
Name 
FROM 
MSysObjects 
WHERE 
Name Not Like 'MSys*'
AND 
Type In (1,4,6)
ORDER BY Name
```

or this one

```
SELECT 
Name 
FROM 
MSysObjects 
WHERE 
(
(Name Not Like ""MSys*"") 
AND 
(Type In (1,4,6))
)
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Note I think the Like should be 'value' instead of quotes / double quotes.

Comment: The problem isn't that my query is not a well formed statement. I would be getting a completely different error message in that scenario. I just use double quotes as a C# specific thing. If I change my query as you suggest, I still get an Ambiguous Outer Join error message.